# Winapi AppendMenu LPCTSTR variable ampersand

Tags: c, winapi

I'm currently beginning learning WINAPI and have been following the tutorials on http://www.winprog.org

On this specific [tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/menus.html), there is a section where the sub menu is created using `AppendMenu`.

The final arg to this is a LPCTSTR, which as i understand would not really be interpreted by anything and is just a string, so shouldn't be the address of anything.

```
AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&File");
                                                         ^
```

So i was wondering why the author includes `&` before the text for the menu button.
Removing the ampersand appears to make no difference to the functionality of the program, but as it doesn't appear in the string that is displayed I'm assuming it does something.

So the question is whether this `&` actually provides any functionality and if so when should it be used ?

Comment: The & symbol cause the F to be underlined. It also means that Alt-F will activate this menu item. See the **Menu Access Keys** heading in this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks, can't believe i didn't find that myself! For anyone else it is specifically mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Menu_Access_Keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampersand is a placeholder for [menu access key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Menu_Access_Keys). The following letter is underlined, and Windows can be set up to show the underscore always, or when Alt key is pressed. The underlined letter is an access key, so when particular menu is open you can press the key to activate the menu item. If there is more than one menu item with that access key pressing the key will select them one by one, but you'd have to press Enter to activate the selected menu item.